# Prefilling from Google Payments

Tags: java, android, google-pay

I have a screen in my Android app where we require the user to enter a card number and the corresponding PIN number for it (ignore the security risks of this) and it would be nice if we could prefill the data from Google Pay if they have it stored.

I have the following layout, trimmed down to the essentials:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <!-- Id -->

    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:hint="User Id">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtUserId"
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Card Number -->

    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:hint="Card number">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtCardNumber"
                android:inputType="number"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- PIN Number -->

    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:hint="PIN Number">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtPin"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:inputType="numberPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this state when I click on the credit card field it will properly try to prefill in my credit card stored in Google (verifying the CCV first through a Google Pay modal) without me needing to do anything. **The BAD thing** is that is also puts the CCV into the PIN field, which is not correct since it's where you put in your PIN number if you were trying to make a payment with the card at a POS device.

If I put `importantForAutofill="no"` on the PIN field then it makes nothing prefill at all, even if I put `importantForAutofill="yes"` and `android:autofillHints="creditCardNumber"` on the card number field.

Similarly if I do it programatically, it makes nothing prefill:

```
inputId.setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO);
inputCardNumber.setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_YES);
inputCardNumber.setAutofillHints(View.AUTOFILL_HINT_CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER);
inputPin.setImportantForAutofill(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO);
```

How can I make a card number prefill from Google Pay without the CCV incorrectly prefilling into a PIN field?

Comment: Hi! I my not be understanding the problem. It looks to me that you want to prevent the CVV from being shown in the PIN field, and that setting the autofill flag on that field achieves that, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, if you are trying to perform a payment online, aren't you be able to do that without using the PIN?